# C system calls pipe, fork, and execl

Tags: c++, c, exec, fork, pipe

I fork()'d a child process and created pipes between them and am able to send argument argv[1] to the child. I want the child to take that filename provided from argv[1] and perform an execl("/bin/cat","cat",(char *) 0);
How do I route the filename piped to the child to the execl?

Enclose is my code for clearity :

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   int fds[2];
   char buffer[100];
   int status;

   if(pipe(fds) == -1){
      perror("pipe creation failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   switch (fork()){

    case 0://child
       close(fds[1]); //close stdout so can only do stdin
       read(fds[0],buffer,strlen(argv[1]));
       printf("from parent: %s\n",argv[1]);
       execl("/bin/cat","cat",(char*)0);
       perror("cat failed");
       exit(20);
       break;

      case -1: //fork failure
       perror("fork failure");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

      default: //parent 
       close(fds[0]); //close stdin so only can do stdout
       write(fds[1],argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));             
   }   

   return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you writing the filename through the pipe when `fork()` preserves `argv[1]`?

You're not checking your read length against your buffer length.

You're not transmitting the trailing nul (`strlen()` doesn't include it) so the filename string's terminator in `buffer` is uninitialized.  Append `+1` to all of your `strlen()` values to correct that.  Then,

```
execl("/bin/cat","cat",buffer,(char*)0);
```

will do what you ask for, but you've closed `stdout` so the `cat` (not the `execl`) will fail, and you're not checking its exit code.

Comment: Thanks, let me ask you another question then.  I want to send a string to the child where the child sorts the string and sends it to another child to remove duplicates. how can I pass out put of one exec() to another child?

Comment: @user2250263 make `stdout` a pipe to the child with `close()` and `dup2()`