# execlp redirect stdin in c

Tags: c, redirect, io

Question is simple

I've searched around but I couldn't find the solution

```
char *data1;
char *data2;
pid_t pid = fork();
int stat;

if (pid == 0){
    execlp("Program B");
} else {
    wait(&stat);
    if (WIFEXITED(stat))
        printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(stat));
}
```

the thing is I need to send `data1` and `data2` to Program B as stdin

but I couldn't find the solution

how can I deal with this?

Comment: You may take the example in this manual page as a starting point: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Comment: I have de-ja-vu - been asked recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244812/read-from-pipe-c/22244897#22244897 (or have I reached senility)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *data1 = "First message.\n";
    char *data2 = "What the rest of the world has been waiting for.\n";
    pid_t pid;
    int p[2];
    if (pipe(p) < 0)
        perror("pipe() failed");
    else if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        perror("fork() failed");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(p[0]);
        close(p[1]);
        execlp("cat", "cat", (char *)0);
        perror("execlp() failed");
    }
    else
    {
        close(p[0]);
        write(p[1], data1, strlen(data1));
        write(p[1], data2, strlen(data2));
        close(p[1]);
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("%d exited with status %d\n", corpse, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note how many closes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide data as argument list to the new process.

Syntax:- `int execlp(const char *path, const char *arg0, ..., NULL);`

So your call can look something like this

```
// convert the input data into string format i.e data1 and data2 should be strings 
execlp("Program B","Program B",data1,data2,NULL);
```

In program B use appropriately to convert it into whatever type you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Building a pipe to `stdin` is the way to go,

Like

```
char *data1;
char *data2;
int stat;
pid_t pid;

if( pipe(pfd) < 0 ) {
perror("pipe");
return 1;
}

pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
    // Close the writing end of the pipe
    close(pfd[1]);
    execlp("Program B");
} 
else if(pid==-1) 
{
    perror("fork");
}
else    
{
    // Write to the pipe.
    if (write(pfd[1], "This is my data \n", 16) != 16)
        perror("write");

    close(pfd[1]);

    wait(&stat);
    if (WIFEXITED(stat))
    printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(stat));
}
```

Comment: Nearly. In the child, you need to connect the read end of the pipe to the standard input (probably `dup2()` followed by another `close()`).  The parent should close the read end of the pipe, though in this case it won't do any harm, I think.